# Is it always possible to get local basis elements of a vector field module on a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying about vector fields from Schuller's lectures on youtube. Given a smooth manifold $M$, if we have a smooth module $\Gamma(TM)$ consisting of all smooth vector fields on the manifold, it's clear to me that we can't get **global** "basis vector fields". In other words we can't come up with a global component representation of vector fields (in terms of the basis vector fields) on the entire manifold.

However, I'm unsure if it's possible to **always** come up with even **local** *basis vector fields*.

Given a vector field $X\in\Gamma(TM)$, is it **always** possible to come up with a local basis representation of the vector field $X$?

Would be grateful if anyone could clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any chart $(U,x)$ on the manifold $M$ gives rise to a local basis of vector fields defined on $U$,$\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{m}}\right\}$, where $m= \dim M$; i.e for every $p\in U$, $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}(p), \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{m}}(p)\right\}$ is a basis for $T_pM$.